# How can I make the state persist in localStorage by using React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks

I made a simple todo app in React with hooks. I created a context file and imported it into the main App component and I created a reducer file and imported it too into the main App. I now want to make the state(the items commig from the context file) getting saved into the localState and then loaded back into the app everytime I reload the browser.

I have created a custom hook, after doing some research but I still couldn't figure out how to solve the problem. The code is shown below.

```
 function usePersistedState(key, defaultVal) {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(() => {
    return localStorage.getItem(key) || defaultVal;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(myState));
  }, [key, myState]);

  return [myState, setMyState];
}
```

[Codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-persist-in-localstorage-hooks-icm97)

I want to use the hook that I have already created to handle the localStorage of my app's state.

Comment: Please add the code on the question, not only in external links

Comment: First thing I see is initial state not being deserialized, `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))`